# Importacion CSV - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: csv, fileupload, importación, subida-de-archivos

Buena tarde comunidad,

Me encuentro trabajando en la importación de CSV mediante ASP.NET MVC, siguiendo varios ejemplos y realizando pruebas, en el momento de depuración me surge la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte del código es el siguiente:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        List<Impreso> impreso = new List<Impreso>();
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            //Read the contents of CSV file.
            string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            //Execute a loop over the rows.
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {                      
                    impreso.Add(new Impreso
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                        Nombre2 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[1]),
                        Nombre3 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[2]),
                        Nombre4 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[3]),
                        Nombre5 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[4])
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return View(impreso);
    }
```

El cual desconozco que pudiera causar el error, o si falta algo que agregar para que pudiese realizar la importación. Adicional a esto cambie el nombre de mis campos originales por Nombre1, etc...

Agradeciendo mucho de sus amables comentarios, cabe mencionar que es la primera vez que realizo importaciones usando este tipo de archivos.

Nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora que asignas el valor a la lista en el `impreso.Add(new Impreso` la cadena string tiene algo erroneo, puede que no se pueda convertir a int o double o que venga vacia, revisa lo que trae el `row` y revisa el resulado de `row.Split(',')[0], row.Split(',')[1], row.Split(',')[2]....`

El problema se da al intentar convertir los nombres de las columnas a double o int por lo que para saltarse esa primera fila podria hacer algo como esto:

```
  
//Execute a loop over the rows.
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                { 
                    int i = 0;
                    bool isNumber = int.TryParse(row.Split(',')[0], out i);                 
                    if(!isNumber)
                      continue;
                    impreso.Add(new Impreso
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                        Nombre2 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[1]),
                        Nombre3 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[2]),
                        Nombre4 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[3]),
                        Nombre5 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[4])
                    });
                }
            }
```

Si es true es un numero, de lo contrario es otro tipo de dato.
O podria hacer esto, agregar un contador para saltarse la primera linea:

```
int count = 0;
//Execute a loop over the rows.
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    if(count == 0)
                      continue;
                    impreso.Add(new Impreso
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                        Nombre2 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[1]),
                        Nombre3 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[2]),
                        Nombre4 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[3]),
                        Nombre5 = Convert.ToDouble(row.Split(',')[4])
                    });
                }
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: Buena tarde Edson, revise con el breakpoint el row y solo puedo visualizar el nombre de las columnas separadas por comas. Revise impreso y el count me lo trae en 0.

Comment: Creo que ahi esta el problema, esta tratando de convertir los nombres de la columnas en int o double, tienes que saltarte la primera fila que seria el nombre de la columnas para luego seguir con los datos.

Comment: Así es, revisando me indicaba que no se podía convertir string to double, el cual para no tener esa excepción puse los Convert, en este caso mi duda es ¿Cómo sería lo que me comentas de saltarme la primera fila?

Comment: Acabo de agregar a mi respuesta las posibles soluiones

Comment: Gracias Edson por tu amable apoyo, tus ejemplos me ayudaron muchísimo. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Con mucho gusto, si te sirvio mi respuesta podrias marcarla para que la pregunta quede como respondida. Saludos cordiales.